# How to replace all content in a column in handsontable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I parse data into handsontable and i click button. I want replace all row in column "A". after change each row in column "A" look like(101, 102, 103), keep data in other columns. Anyone can help me? Thank you.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  var data = [
    
    ["2008", 10, 11, 12, 13],
    ["2009", 20, 11, 14, 13],
    ["2010", 30, 15, 12, 13]
  ];
  
  var $container = $("#example1");
  $container.handsontable({
    data: data,
    startRows: 5,
    startCols: 5,
    colHeaders: true,
    minSpareRows: 1
  });

});
```

```css
</style><!-- Ugly Hack due to jsFiddle issue: http://goo.gl/BUfGZ -->

<script src="http://handsontable.com/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://handsontable.com/dist/jquery.handsontable.full.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="http://handsontable.com/dist/jquery.handsontable.full.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="http://handsontable.com/demo/css/samples.css?20140331">

<style type="text/css">
body {background: white; margin: 20px;}
h2 {margin: 20px 0;}
```

```html
<div class="handsontable" id="example1"></div>

<p>
  <button name="dump" data-dump="#example1" title="Prints current data source to Firebug/Chrome Dev Tools">Dump
    data to console
  </button>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this code:

```
  var newData=[101,102,103];//your data

  $.each(newData,function(i,v){
    $('#example1').handsontable('setDataAtCell', i, 0, v);
  })
```